# OPENOCD Flashing a FT2232 Chip

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ftdi, openocd

I am currently trying to flash a board through a FTDI2232H chip. 
For this purpose I use openocd with the vendors config file

```
sudo openocd -f lpc2xxx_asctecusbjtag05.cfg
```

which looks like this:

```
interface ft2232
ft2232_layout oocdlink
ft2232_vid_pid 0x0403 0xbaf8
jtag_khz 5
telnet_port 4444
gdb_port 3333
                          ...
```

However, I always get the error

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0 (2018-01-24-01:05)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Error: The specified debug interface was not found (ft2232)
The following debug interfaces are available:
1: parport
2: dummy
3: ftdi
4: usb_blaster
5: amt_jtagaccel
6: gw16012
7: usbprog
8: jlink
9: vsllink
10: rlink
11: ulink
12: arm-jtag-ew
13: buspirate
14: remote_bitbang
15: hla
16: osbdm
17: opendous
18: aice
19: cmsis-dap
```

I suspect that this is caused by missing libraries lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0:

```
 sudo apt-get install -y lib32z1 lib32bz2-1.0
```

Currently, I am using the 64Bit version of ubuntu 16.
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue,
respectively where I can find/add the corresponding FT2232H interface and how I have to implement this with openocd?

Thanks a lot for your help!
Best,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

> I use openocd with the vendors config file

This vendor config is too old. Looks like it written for OpenOCD  0.7.0 or earlier. For now, OpenOCD supports a couple of FTDI chips and config syntax changed.

Try

```
interface ftdi
ftdi_vid_pid 0x0403 0xbaf8

# 1 for FT2232H channel B
#ftdi_channel 1
```

Layout command also changed. See `ftdi_layout_init` and `ftdi_layout_signal` in OpenOCD guide. There is `interface/ftdi/oocdlink.cfg` file -- try to use `ftdi_layout_*` from this file.

See `intrface/ftdi` directory for cfg examples.